# Find $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}A_n$ and $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}A_n$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am new to probability theory and doing some exercise behind a textbook "A Probability Path" written by Resnick.

I have a sense that the $\limsup A_n=(0,1]$ and $\liminf A_n=0$. I am not sure whether I am right or not. But I hope someone can show me some idea.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean $\limsup = \liminf =0$?

Comment: But if $\limsup=0$, then for $\liminf$, I don't see any possible result which could be smaller than 0.

Comment: My apology.  I confused least upper bound (lim sup) with greatest lower bound (lim inf).  I have therefore deleted my confusing comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\limsup_n A_n$ is the collection of elements that are in $A_n$ infinitely often.

$\liminf_n A_n$ is the collection of elements that are in $A_n$ for all but a finite number of $n$.

It is clear that $\liminf_n A_n \subset \limsup_n A_n$.

You are given $a_n >0, b_n >1$ and $a_n \to 0, b_n \to 1$.

Hence if $x \in (0,1]$ we see that $x \in A_n$ for $n$ greater than some $N$ (dependent on $x$, of course). Hence $x \in \liminf_n A_n$.

Note that if $y \le 0$ then $y \notin A_n$ for any $n$. Also, if $y >1$ then after some $N$ we have $b_n < y$. Hence $\liminf_n A_n = \limsup_n A_n = (0,1]$.

Comment: Are you saying that $\limsup A_n = \liminf A_n = (0,1]$?

Comment: Not just saying it, but writing it too :-).

Comment: Oh, thanks. I accidentally ignored your last statement. Sorry.

Comment: It seems that you first show that $(0,1]$ is a $\liminf$, then you show that any set bigger would not become a $\limsup$, which means it is also a $\limsup$ by the property in your 3rd line.

Comment: Well, there are no elements that are present infinitely often but also not present infinitely often, so the $\liminf,\limsup$ are the same.